# Dynamic forms: Remove selected form index pertaining to an item successfully removes item from list but form still shows removed item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm making a dynamic form where one could add/remove forms as needed. E.g. allowing users to add an item to a list by entering that item name in the form. To do this, I have

```
this.state = {
item_list: [] 
}

removeItem = (index, e) => {
    this.setState({
      item_list: this.state.item_list.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
    }, () => {
      // callback
      console.log(index);
      console.log(this.state.item_list);
    });
  }

render() {
return(
//some other code
{this.state.item_list.map((val, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
      <Header> Item #{index+1} </Header> 
      <Form> </Form>
      <Button onClick={(e) => this.removeItem(index, e)} color="red"> <Icon name= "minus"/>Remove Item </Button>
      </div>
    ))}
)
}
```

The console shows that whenever i remove an item/form, the correct item is removed from `item_list`. However, the rendered forms always show only the "last item" was removed from `item_list`. E.g. if I have 3 items `["A", "B", "C"]`, and I remove item "B", `item_list = ["A", "C"]` but the displayed forms show `["A", "B"]`.

I suspect this has something to do with me displaying the form items based on index (map(val, index)) and not a unique key, but I'm not sure how to solve this in a straightforward manner (I tried to include the unique key in `div` but I doubt that's the solution).

I'm a newbie when it comes to React so I'd appreciate some directions regarding this. Sorry if this is trivial, and thanks to anyone helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the entries in `item_list` are unique strings, change the div to use `key={val}` instead of `key={index}`.

By using the `index` you're telling React to reuse the existing component instance for the matching index, which isn't what you want because the indices change as items are added or removed.

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response! An issue I find with this is that if the person has yet to fill out the form, `val` would not be readily available when they want to remove the item from the list. This also throws errors on React "Encountered two children with the same key "" " since `val` would be an empty string. Do you know a potential workaround? 
Thank you so much

Comment: You could generate a guid or random ID for the values and use that. Without knowing the specifics of your data it’s hard to prescribe a specific solution.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I tried using UUIDs to no avail until I realize it was a dumb mistake on my end: I forgot to set the `value` prop in the Input forms to refer to the state array's item. WIthout setting this, the presented form has a static value that does not change with the state array value. Apologies, a really dumb mistake but thanks for helping me brainstorm!

Answer (score 0):

A very trivial mistake! Turns out I forgot to set the value prop in the `Input` forms to refer to the state array's item. Without setting this, the presented form has a static value that does not change with the state array value.